# MySQL stopped running on Ubuntu: Can't change to run as user 'mysql'. How to save data?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Today out of the blue stopped running MySQL on a Ubuntu server.
When I try to log in there, I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Inspecting the error:

```
mysqld --verbose

160408  3:21:24 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160408  3:21:24 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user exists!

160408  3:21:24 [ERROR] Aborting

160408  3:21:24 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I tried `sudo service mysql start`:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

I also tried:

```
ps ax | grep mysql
 4127 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

and

```
sudo chown mysql:root -R /var/lib/mysql
chown: invalid user: `mysql:root'
```

I also checked if I am not running out of space on the server:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        79G   27G   49G  35% /
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  204K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

But there's plenty of space.

If I try to check the socket: `cd /var/run/mysqld/`, then:

```
-bash: cd: /var/run/mysqld/: No such file or directory
```

How to fix this issue? Or at least - how to save the data from the database?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: You only quoted half of the error message in your question title, which is strange given that the other half told you what to do: "Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  ***Please check that the user exists***"